# Rails LoadError when trying to start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, debugging

I'm following SaaS from edX and I'm trying to run my rails server that I created using

```
rails s
```

and it keeps throwing a load error for

```
gem/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: 
undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread
```

I'm not quite sure what I can do to fix this, or what other info would be required to help me solve this. I'm sorry for such a vague post but ruby on rails is rather new to me and I'm not sure why its throwing this

ive tried

```
gem install rails
```

and i get a permissions error

*Edit 1

Gemfile The debug19 is what i was told to put in per my instructions from edX 169.1

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
gem 'haml'
# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
group :development ,:test do
  gem 'ruby-debug19' , :require => 'ruby-debug'
end
```

Comment: can you link to the blog entry you say you're following?

Comment: also, can you post the contents of your Gemfile? I'm surprised you have ruby-debug-base19 in there at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your environment to give an exact answer, but you can try removing `ruby-debug-base19` and `ruby-debug` from your Gemfile. You can also see if it's being installed by another gem by looking for references to them in your Gemfile.lock. If they are dependencies, remove the gems they depend on as well.

Comment: They were added in by me, as to the course im following the enviroment is the one i was given by them.